# Find XML CDATA for special character (capital L with dot over it)

Tags: xml, unicode, cdata

This [web page](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/unicode/unicsel/latkomb.htm) has some data about the character I need (capital L with dot over it). It's about halfway down the page.

But I don't know how to turn that into CDATA. for example, here's what I'm doing for a bar over X.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&#772;]]></xsl:text>
```

What CDATA would I do for L with a dot over it?

Update, this CDATA template is my leading solution:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">L<![CDATA[&#775;]]></xsl:text>
```

It tested well in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to introduce a CDATA section - or work around the problem that it introduces by disabling output escaping. It's unnecessarily complicated. What you have entered should result in an identical infoset when parsed to:

```
<xsl:text>L̇</xsl:text>
```

If it doesn't, then you've got a deeper Unicode problem in your stack, eg not serving the output in UTF-8 (in which case you should fix that problem first), or using a text editor with no Unicode support (in which case you can use the numeric character reference `L&#775;` or `L&#x0307;` if you like).

If you are seeing the dot appear in an unexpected place that's a font rendering problem in your browser/editor and not anything to do with XML. When you use a combining diacritical such as the macron (U+0304, 772) or the dot-above (U+0307, 775) for unusual combinations like X-macron and L-dot that don't appear in any modern language, it's very unlikely indeed that the font you are using will have a nicely precomposed glyph for that combination.

Instead you will get a crude overlay of two shapes, and it'll be pot luck whether they line up at all. Worst case, the font doesn't have glyphs for the combining characters at all, in which case the display engine will typically fall back to a different font entirely, which makes it even less likely that the result will be pretty.

In general, common fonts/web browsers aren't that great at combining even the common diacriticals that real languages use; trying to use the feature for arbitrary combinations is most likely to result in messy Z̛al͏go̵t̸e͝x҉t̷.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CDATA at all. You can just use `L̇`.

In this, the CDATA is being used to stop the character reference being turned into a `L̇` by the XSL engine. i.e. so that `&#772;` is output instead of `L̇`.

There isn't any need for that though, since you can just use a raw `L̇` everywhere.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">L̇</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Thanks. That dot is off to the side. I Googled more and found this <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">L<![CDATA[&#775;]]></xsl:text>  ..the 775 put the dot over the previous letter. I think.